# Get Kubernetes Errors and Logs on GCE

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

We would need to get error events (like pod x is stuck in a crash loop, etc.) from Kubernetes itself.
On Google Container Engine we can not find those logs anywhere and therefor can not add monitoring to it.

Those Logs are usually provided by the API Server etc. which is not included in Google Logging. Is there a way of achieving what we need?
Additionally it would be good to have those K8s Errors in the GCE Error Reporting.

Comment: Feel free to file a feature request against Error Reporting here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187271&template=1010940

There are many more components where you might want to chime in.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm... `kubectl describe pod` and `kubectl logs pod` should work for you. What I learned about using them came from

https://kukulinski.com/10-most-common-reasons-kubernetes-deployments-fail-part-1/

and references therein

Answer (score 0):

you can run hyperkube docker image with Docker CMD 
`watch -n 10 kubectl describe pod <podname>`